# Invalid date:Error while import CSV to Cassandra using pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I'm using Jupyter NoteBook to run pySpark code to import CSV file to Cassandra v3.11.3. Getting below error.

---

```
... 1 more[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]---------------------------------------------------------------------------

pySpark Code i have attached as picture:

```
[![pyspark_code][1]][1]
```

Any inputs...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without the full trace it's hard to know exactly where this is failing. The method you pasted is just the p4yj wrapper method and we really would need to see the underlying Java Exception.

From what I can tell it looks like you are attempting to also use some options on the C* write that are unsupported. For example "MODE" - "DROPMALFORMED" is not a valid C* connector option. DataFrame Writer and Reader options are source specific so you are unfortunately unable to mix and match.

This makes me think that the data being written actually has a malformed date string or two and this code is dying when attempting to write the broken record. One way around this would be to attempt to do the date casting on CSV read which I believe does support *DROPMALFORMED* style parsing options.

Comment: I have updated the log file... I will try apply DROPMALFORMED in read... will update you the results.

Comment: The trace shows exactly what I was saying, a string which is attempting to be written to C* is found to be not convertable by the Spark Casasndra Connector. Your best case is to make the column a Timestamp/Date Column in SparkSQL before writing to make sure your values are all valid.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not a developer I just followed few of the links to get here, 
I have removed 'DROPMALFORMED' and tried still same error I'm getting... the reason I applied this 'DROPMALFORMED' as csv format was not displaying correctly so. Please let me know if we can talk or I can share more information if you need.  or can you share me any other way I can write data via CSV, I have ruby code with me which is working, but it is taking very long time to complete and I have lot of data to insert it to cassandra. I thought pySpark can complete faster.